# Trouble understanding value iteration

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have trouble understanding how the value iteration algorithm for
MDP:s work. I'm trying to follow the [canonical grid world example](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss03/ams/DecisionProblems.pdf)
(slide 17),
but I don't get the correct results. Here's my work:

Initially I set the value function to 0 everywhere. So the matrix
representation of each state's utility becomes:
$$
V_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -999 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$-999$ is arbitrarily choosen as a dummy value for the square that
can't be entered. Then I use the Bellman update to calculate values
for the next iteration,
$$
V_{t+1}(s) = R(s) + \max_a\sum_{s'}P(s'|a, s)V_t(s'),
$$
where $P(s'|a, s)$ is the probability of reaching state $s'$ given
current state $s$ and action $a$. Using the values found in the PDF,
the utility for square at row 1 column 4 at time step 1 is calculated
to
$$
V_1((1, 4)) = 1 + \max_a\sum_{s'}P(s'|a, (1,4))V_0(s') = 1.
$$
$V_1((2, 4)) = -1$ is calculated similarily, yielding the matrix
$$
V_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -999 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I again use the Bellman update to calculate $V_2((1,4))$
$$
V_2((1,4)) = R((1,4)) + \max_a\sum_{s'}P(s'|a, (1,4))V_1(s')\\
= 1 + \max_a\sum_{s'}P(s'|a, (1,4))V_1(s').
$$
$a = \mathrm{n}$ (as in go "north") is obviously the action that maximizes the
expression. Then $P((1,4)|\mathrm{n},(1,4)) = 0.9$ and
$P((1,3)|\mathrm{n},(1,4)) = 0.1$ and I get:
$$
V_2((1,4)) = 1 + P((1,4)|\mathrm{n}, (1,4))V_1((1,4)) + P((1,3)|\mathrm{n}, (1,4))V_1((1,3))\\
= 1 + 0.9\cdot1 + 0.1\cdot0 = 1.9
$$
But this result is not correct the value should remain at 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pdf you link doesn't explain the MDP fully - key points are (1) when the rewards are granted (exiting or entering a cell) and (2) how terminal states are handled. This is required in order to explain where your mistake is using the same terms as you. Could you please add this missing information?

Comment: I don't have more details than what is described in the PDF, but there are many variants of the problem on the net. The reward is a function from state to a value $R(s) = some number$. There's a video of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glHKJ359Cnc but again I dont understand why the reward for the top corner square doesn't grow above 100. Given the equation it should!

Comment: The problem is with your interpretation of the how those rewards and the MDP works. So it is somewhat important to know what interpretation you are *trying* to use. I can choose one that works and might be what is intended and answer on that basis . . . however, it may conflict with something you have read. That will be because the version you have read will solve in a slightly different way that still addresses the problem you are observing.

Comment: I can go ahead and answer on that basis if you like? But please bear in mind that some things you have got wrong, other things might be different because I haven't read the same sources as you - I won't be able to tell you what those are, or correct any misunderstandings you have translating from my explanation to whatever you are using

Comment: I'm trying to use whatever the interpretation is in the pdf and video so that my results match theirs. If the problem is underspecified in the pdf or video I couldn't tell because I wouldn't have any idea what is missing. By searching "gridworld value iteration" you can find many more examples very similar to the one in my examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing how the episode terminates, and possible confusing the difference between reward granted from arriving in a state with reward granted when leaving a state (or other ways of assigning reward).

Working backwards from the correct answers in [the slides you linked](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss03/ams/DecisionProblems.pdf), it looks like a grid world, where either:

- Reward $R(s)$ is granted for *leaving* a state $s$, with the +1, -1 reward values associated with the squares as shown (this happens to then equal their utility as I will explain later). In addition there is a not-shown terminal state which is reached by taking *any* action in either of the squares that grant reward. A terminal state has a fixed value of 0.
- Reward $R(s)$ is granted for *entering* a state $s$. Separate to this, the +1, -1 rewards are written on the terminal states to show them as targets, in the same place as the utility is written on other states. It might be better to show green and red colours or some other indicator of good vs bad terminal state instead in this case to avoid confusion between rewards and utilities.

You can also take either interpretation and make a consistent answer with it. However, I am assuming the first option, reward is granted for *leaving* a state, in the rest of this answer.

The first thing this means is that your assertion:

> $a = \mathrm{n}$ (as in go "north") is obviously the action that maximizes the expression

is not correct. It doesn't matter what the action is, the state $(1,4)$ always transitions to state $T$ (the terminal state) granting reward $1$, regardless of the action. In addition $V(T) = 0$ by definition, because no future reward is possible for state $T$.

This means that your update for $(1,4)$ is always the same:

$$V_{n+1}((1,4) = R((1,4)) + \max_a\sum_{s'}P(s'|a, (1,4))V_n(s')\\
= 1 + V_n(T) = 1$$

Note your original maths would be correct if the episode *never terminated* - in which case it should be possible to get a high expected long-term utility by moving to $(1,4)$ and continuing to move North from it. However, that is clearly not the intent of the presented material. They give the expected converged values later in the document, and they are consistent with this view.

Once you allow for the fixed utility of $0$ for terminal states, you should find that updates to all the other states converge to the values you see in the document, using the update mechanism that you are applying.